# Does anyone manufacture ISO 590 36h rims?

Tags: wheels

I'm rebuilding an old english three speed, including new wheels. I've done this in the past and used Sun rims. I need ISO 590 rims, which seem to be readily available in 40-hole and 32-hole construction, but the 36-hole construction doesn't seem to be available anywhere. I see entries for this on various websites but everything is out of stock.

Is there a reliable manufacturer making these currently?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid I'm not sure this is actually a question we can answer here, since providing specific recommendations may not work in the long term.  You might ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) though, since a number of our more knowledgeable members wander through there.

Comment: Jbi has 36h 590 cr18s currently.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting close votes under the belief it's asking for a product recommendation.  It's not asking for a recommendation, it's asking if a product *exists*, which is an objective fact.

Comment: I have used 584 (650B) as an alternative in the past, much better choice of rims and tyres if your brakes allow for the 3mm difference